# How to find the sum of two linear subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 
$U=\{(x,y,z)|x=y=z\}$ and 
$W=\{(x,y,z)|x=0\}$.

How do I find $U+W$?

Comment: First imagine U and W geometrically in 3-D. Then you are more likely to get an answer intuitively, which you can then write out more formally. eg. Is the first one a line ? What type ?  is the second one a plane ? How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to find a basis for each of the individual subspaces. Then combine those bases together and remove any of those vectors that are linearly dependent on the previous ones. What is left is a basis of your sum space.

Your $U$ has the single basis vector $(1,1,1)$, and your $W$ has the two basis vectors $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Check if those are linearly dependent and describe the span of the union of those bases.

Comment: they are linearly independent.so dimension is 3.so they span $R^{3}$